# d3 conflict between multiple area charts in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I need to add multiple area charts in the same page, like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jubri/fBTxS/4/):

```
<area-chart></area-chart>
<area-chart></area-chart>
```

The problem is that the two area charts seem to conflict and the lines seem to be removed from one  chart and added to the other. It works well with only one chart (`<area-chart></area-chart>`) in the page ([see the fiddle working well with one chart only](http://jsfiddle.net/jubri/fBTxS/5/)), but not with multiple.

Any ideas on how to fix this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQRPu/)

You should declare a variable `data` with `var`